# Tkinter Checkbox issues

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

Edit: Changed to use TopLevel and the radio buttons

I am working on making a python chess game for the fun of it and I am coming at a slight problem with creating a checkbox.

In the standard game of chess, if the pawn reaches the other side of the chessboard, the player will be able to choose what chess piece they want.

Well, I wanted to give the user a checkbox to check the item they wanted and then the box would disappear(destroyed). Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

def AddChessPiece():
    CheckBox = TopLevel()

    print("Im in The checkbox function")
    CheckVar1 = IntVar()
    CheckVar2 = IntVar()
    CheckVar3 = IntVar()
    CheckVar4 = IntVar()

    C1 = Radiobutton(CheckBox, text="Rook",variable = CheckVar1, command = lambda: PieceName("Rook"))
    C2 = Radiobutton(CheckBox, text="Knight",variable = CheckVar2,command= lambda: PieceName("Knight"))
    C3 = Radiobutton(CheckBox, text="Bishop",variable = CheckVar3,command= lambda: PieceName("Bishop"))
    C4 = Radiobutton(CheckBox, text="Queen",variable = CheckVar4, command= lambda: PieceName("Queen"))

    C1.pack()
    C2.pack()
    C3.pack()
    C4.pack()


    CheckBox.mainloop()
    print("Im leaving the checkbox function")
```

What it is doing is that it creates the window, then when checked, it sends the item to the lambda function. The problem is that

1. I don't know where or how to destroy it immediately after the item has been clicked and
2. It seems like the program doesn't continue when it goes into the function PieceName. It goes through the complete function but it never prints "I'm Leaving the checkbox function". I'm thinking this might be an error since I destroyed the function.Any help would be wonderful!

Here is the PieceName Method if you're curious. I don't think it will help anything though. What is does is it Adds the new coordinates to new chess piece first(Depending if its player 1 (White Chess Piece) or player 2 (Black chess piece) turn to go) and then removes the pawns coordinates.

```
def PieceName(name):
    global Player1, CurrentChessPiece, IndexVal,White_Pieces,Black_Pieces

    if(Player1 == True):
        FullName = "White_" + name
        NewPieceIndex = White_Pieces.index(FullName)
        White_Pieces[NewPieceIndex].coordinates.append(CurrentChessPiece.coordinates[IndexVal])
    else:
        FullName = "Black_" + name
        NewPieceIndex = Black_Pieces.index(FullName)
        Black_Pieces[NewPieceIndex].coordinates.append(CurrentChessPiece.coordinates[IndexVal])

    del CurrentChessPiece.coordinates[IndexVal]
    CheckBox.destroy()
    print("Im leaving the PieceName function")
```

Comment: You can't have multiple instances of Tk(). If you are using Tkinter to program your whole game, you should consider using Toplevel() to create extra windows like pop-ups. Also, I think you should consider using radiobuttons since you can only have one selection and an extra button to confirm promotion to avoid misclicks.

Comment: Can you also please edit in your `PieceName` method?

Comment: The Method was added. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This question is now solved!! I replaced CheckBox.destroy() with CheckBox.quit() and added CheckBox.destroy() at the end of the AddChessPiece() function. Thanks for your help Lafexlos. If there is anyway I am able to select you as the one who answered the question (since you did help out), let me know, because you most certainly did.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer (you are encouraged to answer your own questions) for the sake of others who have the same problem.

Comment: I am glad I helped. :) Also, I am on mobile right now and it'll take probably days I'll be on pc, so it's OK that you answer your question and accept it(after cooldown ends in two days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this is the new revision that is now working. What I did was remove all the lambda parameters and just saved all possible values to "CheckVar1". From there I created a messagebox and gave the user the options to choose from the options and click C5 ("Ok button") to quit.

When the ok button was clicked, it closed the widget but did not destroy it, so I was able to still grab "CheckVar1". From there, I called a getter function "CheckVar1.get()" to return the value as a string variable and pass it into the following method "PieceName"

Once the method "PieceName" was finished, "Checkbox" was then destroyed, removing it from the system.

```
def AddChessPiece():
    CheckBox = Toplevel()

    print("Im in The checkbox function")
    CheckVar1 = StringVar() 

    C = Message(CheckBox,text="What did you want to\n replace your pawn for?\n\n",width = 300)
    C1 = Radiobutton(CheckBox, text="Rook",variable = CheckVar1,value ="Rook")
    C2 = Radiobutton(CheckBox, text="Knight",variable = CheckVar1,value = "Knight")
    C3 = Radiobutton(CheckBox, text="Bishop",variable = CheckVar1,value = "Bishop")
    C4 = Radiobutton(CheckBox, text="Queen",variable = CheckVar1,value = "Queen")
    C5 = Button(CheckBox, text="Ok", command=CheckBox.quit)

    C.pack()
    C1.pack()
    C2.pack()
    C3.pack()
    C4.pack()
    C5.pack()

    CheckBox.mainloop()

    PieceName(str(CheckVar1.get()))
    print("Im leaving the checkbox function")
    CheckBox.destroy()
```

This is the second function. The only thing that was changed was that "CheckBox.destroy()" was not used at all in this function. CheckBox wasn't used at all in this function, so this code is now irrelevant to the discussion.

```
def PieceName(name):
    global Player1, CurrentChessPiece, IndexVal,White_Pieces,Black_Pieces
    if(Player1 == True):

    FullName = "White_" + str(name)

    for n in range(0, len(White_Pieces)):   
        if((FullName in White_Pieces[n].name)== True):
            White_Pieces[n].coordinates.append(CurrentChessPiece.coordinates[IndexVal])
    else:
        FullName = "Black_" + str(name)
        for n in range(0,len(Black_Pieces)):
            if((FullName in Black_Pieces[n].name) == True):
                Black_Pieces[n].coordinates.append(CurrentChessPiece.coordinates[IndexVal])

    del CurrentChessPiece.coordinates[IndexVal]
    print("Name is " + str(FullName))
    print("Im leaving the PieceName function")
```

Thanks for all the help!